# Find $k$ such that $k/\ell = n^{\ell - 1}$ for some $\{k, \ell, n\} \subset \mathbb{N}, \ \ell \in (2, 10)$

Tags: number-theory

> > **Challenge:**
> >
> > Find a number $k$ such that when you divide it by $\ell$ the result is $n^{\ell - 1}$ for some $\{k, \ell, n\} \subset \mathbb{N}$ and $\ell \in (2, 10)$.

Obviously $\ell \neq 1$ because $k/\ell = k = n^{\ell - 1} \Leftrightarrow k = \ell = 1$.

And $\ell \neq 2$ because $k/\ell = n^{\ell - 1} \Leftrightarrow k/\ell = n$.

So now let $\ell = 3$ and hope for a solution? This is what I tried and I *did* find a solution for which $k = 108$. In fact, if $\ell = 4$ then $k$ could still equal $108$, because $108/3 = 6^2$ and $108/4 = 3^3$.

Are there other types of numbers like $108$, and if not, what are the other solutions for $k$? Is there a special way to approach this problem without the ol' classic *trial and error*?

Thanks.

Comment: For each $\ell$ there are infinitely many solutions, namely $\{\ell n^{\ell-1} : n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Comment: @amsmath So you are implying that there are infinitely many solutions for $\ell$ and $k \ ($since $k = \ell n^{\ell - 1})?$

Comment: No. For given $\ell$ there are infiitely many solutions for $(k,n)$.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I'm just starting to learn about this stuff...